# Eclipse: Update my app version

Tags: android, eclipse

When I have updated my code, versionCode and versionName in my app and then install the apk file on my phone, it says a new app is being installed but the newest changes in the code is not there. It runs as the version it had the first time I installed the app on my phone.

**How do I update it so it will work?**

I have tried updating the versionName and versionCode in my AndroidManifest.

I have tried uninstalling the app from my phone before the update.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update your app version

1. right click on your project folder in eclipse,
2. select properties,
3. select android,
4. tick the latest version you have updates eg:(Android 5.0).

another way while creating project in eclipse,

1. choose Target SDK to latest.